# slick carousel append Dots

Tags: 7, views

I am using [slick](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick) and [slick views](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick_views) modules.
I want the dots to be under the images..
How can achieve this style: " o o o "  in Append dots??
The information window (next to Append dots box) suggests to try .slick__arrow, but i can't understand where to put it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Slick carousel page at `admin/config/media/slick`, then either add your own optionset or edit the default one provided.

Inside of these option sets, under the "Settings" tab, you will find a checkbox for Dots. Once checked, you'll see more options such as "Dot class" and "Append dots".

[image: Slick Settings UI showing dots]

Then save your optionset, and make sure that your carousel uses that one, as opposed to a different set.

**Edit:** I actually just ran into this problem on my own. I had to download Slick library 1.5.9, and then in the Slick settings (inside the view), I selected Skin: "Default" and it came up for me. Hope it works for you!

Comment: By using the previous settings the carousel seems like this [image]. I want to change each "[object Object]" with dots.  [image]: http://83.212.168.219/DariahCrete/sites/default/files/dots.png

Comment: And you have added the slick library to `sites/.../libraries/slick`, right?

Comment: yes, exactly there...

Comment: I want to find, where this code is created:**********************************<nav class="slick__arrow">
     
<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="previous" style="display: inline-block;">Previous</button>            

<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next slick-arrow" aria-label="next" style="display: inline-block;">Next</button>    </nav>*******************   I want to replace the Button tag with img tag. Do you know where it is created??

Comment: You could either set it in the Slick UI settings after checking "arrows", or use CSS and `background-image` to set it to an image.

Comment: @AlekaSeliniotaki See edited response.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the slick option set, under the "Settings" tab, i checked the box "Arrows" and i changed the code for Previous and Next arrows from the tabs were available there.